# Degree of splitting field of $\big|1+e^{\frac{1}{11}2\pi i}+e^{\frac{3}{11}2\pi i}\big|$ over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: field-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

For $k$ between $1$ and $10$ inclusive, let $\lambda_k=\big|1+e^{\frac{k}{11}2\pi i}+e^{\frac{3k}{11}2\pi i}\big|$. What is the degree of the extension 
${\mathbb Q}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{10})$ over $\mathbb Q$ ?

My thoughts : any individual $\lambda_k$ has minimal polynomial $\lambda^{10} - 12\lambda^8 + 51\lambda^6 - 96\lambda^4 + 80\lambda^2 - 23$. With the help of a computer I learnt that the degree of ${\mathbb Q}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_{3})$ over $\mathbb Q$ is 40, but I was unable to push the computations further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lambda_i^2$ is an algebraic integer of norm $23$ in $\Bbb Z[2\cos(2\pi/11)]$, and so in this ring, the principal ideal $(23)$ splits in the product of principal ideals $\prod_{i=1}^5 (\lambda_i^2)$.

Therefore, the $\lambda_i^2$ are distinct primes and no nontrivial product combination of them can be a square in $\Bbb Z[2\cos(2\pi/11)]$.

This shows that $\Bbb Q((\lambda_i)_{i=1\ldots 10}) = \Bbb Q((\sqrt{\lambda_i^2})_{i=1 \ldots 5})$ has degree $2^5$ over $\Bbb Q(2\cos(2\pi/11))$, and so it has degree $32 \times 5 = 160$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: well it's exactly like proving $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5,\sqrt 7, \sqrt{11}, \sqrt {13})$ has degree $2^5$

Comment: I'm convinced now, thanks. Do you know if the Galois group of $\Bbb Q((\lambda_i)_{i=1\ldots 10})$ over $\mathbb Q$ is Abelian ?

Comment: Also i needed to mention that $23$ doesn't ramify because it's coprime with $11$.

Comment: Computing the Galois group is difficult here, isn't it ? It has order $160$

Comment: well our extension is ramified at $11$ and $23$ but also maybe a bit at $2$ so my statement wasn't completely correct as written

Comment: computing the galois group isn't really too hard, finding non commuting element is also easy, for example consider $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4,\lambda_5) \mapsto (-\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4,\lambda_5)$ and $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4,\lambda_5) \mapsto (\lambda_2,\lambda_4,\lambda_5,\lambda_3,\lambda_1)$

Comment: There's another point that's bothering me now ; what do you make of $\lambda_6,\ldots,\lambda_{10}$. The only "symmetry" property I can see is that $\lambda_k\lambda_{11-k}$ is a real number, but it will not be rational.

Comment: $\lambda_6 = \lambda_5$ because they are the modulus of a pair of conjugates.